# How to trigger state change from child to parent in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

These are in the parent component...

```
   const [setQuantity, quantity] = useState(1);

   const handleSetQuantity = e => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
      console.log("TEST");

      setQuantity(e.target.value);
    };
```

And I am passing it to child component like so:

```
<SomeChildComponent
    setQuantity={e => handleSetQuantity(e)}
    quantity={quantity}
/>
```

Inside the :

```
<select
    onChange={e => props.setQuantity(e)}
    value={props.quantity}
    >
    <option value={1}>1</option>
    <option value={2}>2</option>
    <option value={3}>3</option>
</select>
```

I am able to access the function from child since the "TEST" log appears. However it tells me that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: setQuantity is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? And if so, what is the right way to change parent state from action triggered by child component?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing an executed function, and you should pass the reference.

```
<SomeChildComponent
    setQuantity={handleSetQuantity}
    quantity={quantity}
/>
```

Also,

`const [setQuantity, quantity] = useState(1);`

you swapped the places of the value and the function, should be:

`const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);`

Comment: I realised it too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the method to your child component directly through props

```
<SomeChildComponent
    {setQuantity}
    {quantity}
/>
```

you child components will then be able to use the method as you would in the parent component.

Comment: how do you refer to this in the child component?

Comment: As you would any other props, `function someChildComponent({ setQuantity, quantity })` and then simply call it from this child component `setQuantity(my_value)`